I'm getting error about WebSocket closing unexpectedly
I'm trying to build a multiplayer chess like game where we have three characters: pawn, hero1 and hero2 with each their own characteristics. I have not moved to the development of the game logic yet as I keep getting error with the WebSocket. As soon as I connect to localhost, I get error :
websocket.js:24 WebSocket connection closed unexpectedly, code=1006, reason=
socket.onclose  @   websocket.js:24
Please help me solve this.
I've tried debugging but it keeps giving that message is undefined.
Below is my code:
server/server.js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const http = require('http');
const WebSocket = require('ws');


const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
const GameState = require('./GameState');
const GameRoom = require('./models/GameRoom');

const mongoURI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const server = http.createServer(app);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });
const gameState = new GameState();

mongoose.connect(mongoURI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
}).then(() => console.log('MongoDB connected'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Server is running');
});

app.post('/api/create-room', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const gameRoom = new GameRoom();
    await gameRoom.save();
    res.status(201).json(gameRoom);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error creating game room' });
  }
});

app.post('/api/join-room/:roomId', async (req, res) => {
  const { roomId } = req.params;
  try {
    const gameRoom = await GameRoom.findById(roomId);
    if (!gameRoom) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Room not found' });
    }

    if (gameRoom.players.length < 2) {
      gameRoom.players.push(req.body.playerName);
      await gameRoom.save();
      res.status(200).json(gameRoom);
    } else {
      res.status(400).json({ error: 'Room is full' });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error joining game room' });
  }
});


wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  console.log('New client connected');

  ws.on('message', (message) => {
    console.log(`Received message => ${message}`);
    // Handle incoming messages and game logic
    if (typeof message === 'string') {
      try{
        if (message){
          const data = JSON.parse(message);

          switch (data.type) {
              case 'JOIN_GAME':
                  // Add player to the game state
                  gameState.addPlayer(data.playerId, data.characters);
                  break;
              case 'MOVE':
                  // Process player move
                  gameState.makeMove(data.playerId, data.character, data.targetPosition);
                  break;
              // Add more cases as needed
          }

          // Broadcast updated game state to all players
          broadcastGameState();
          ws.send("Message received");
        }else{
          console.log('Received empty message');
        }
        
      }catch(error){
        console.error('Failed to parse message:', error);
      }
    }else{
      console.error('Invalid message type:', typeof message);
    }
    
  });

  ws.on('close', () => {
    console.log('Client disconnected');
  });

  ws.on('error', (error) => {
    console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
  });
});

// Existing MongoDB connection and Express routes...
function broadcastGameState() {
  const state = JSON.stringify({ type: 'GAME_STATE', gameState: gameState.getGameState() });
  wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
      if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
          client.send(state);
      }
  });
}


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});


server/GameState.js

class GameState {
    constructor() {
        // Initialize the game state
        this.board = this.initializeBoard(); // 5x5 grid
        this.players = {}; // Store player data
        this.turn = null; // Track whose turn it is
        this.moveHistory = []; // Track move history
        this.gameOver = false; // Flag to check if the game is over
    }

    initializeBoard() {
        // Set up initial positions of characters on the board
        // Example: { R0C0: { player: 'Player1', character: 'P' }, ... }
        const board = {};
        for (let row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
            for (let col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
                board[`R${row}C${col}`] = null;
            }
        }
        return board;
    }

    addPlayer(playerId, characters) {
        // Add player to the game state
        this.players[playerId] = {
            characters: characters,
            positions: this.getInitialPositions(playerId, characters), 
        };
        // Logic to decide the first player
        if (!this.turn) {
            this.turn = playerId;
        }
    }

    getInitialPositions(playerId, characters) {
        // Determine initial positions based on selected characters
        // Example logic: Player1 characters on R0, Player2 on R4
        const startingRow = playerId === 'Player1' ? 0 : 4;
        return characters.map((char, index) => `R${startingRow}C${index}`);
    }

    makeMove(playerId, character, targetPosition) {
        if (this.isValidMove(playerId, character, targetPosition)) {
            const currentPosition = this.players[playerId].positions[character];
            this.board[currentPosition] = null; // Clear current position
            this.board[targetPosition] = { player: playerId, character: character }; // Set new position
            this.players[playerId].positions[character] = targetPosition; // Update character position

            // Add to move history
            this.moveHistory.push({ playerId, character, move: targetPosition });

            // Check if the game is over
            this.checkGameOver();

            // Switch turn
            this.switchTurn();
        }
    }

    isValidMove(playerId, character, targetPosition) {
        // Validate if the move is within the game rules
        return true; // Placeholder logic
    }

    switchTurn() {
        // Switch turn to the other player
        this.turn = this.turn === 'Player1' ? 'Player2' : 'Player1';
    }

    checkGameOver() {
        // Check if one player has no remaining characters and end the game
        // Set this.gameOver to true if the game is over
    }

    getGameState() {
        // Return the current game state for sending to the clients
        return {
            board: this.board,
            players: this.players,
            turn: this.turn,
            moveHistory: this.moveHistory,
            gameOver: this.gameOver,
        };
    }
}

module.exports = GameState;


server/models/GameRoom.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const gameRoomSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  players: {
    type: Array,
    default: [],
  },
  gameState: {
    type: String,
    default: 'waitingForPlayers',
  },
  moveHistory: {
    type: Array,
    default: [],
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('GameRoom', gameRoomSchema);


frontend/src/CharacterSelection.jsx
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
const CharacterSelection = ({ onSelectionComplete }) => {
  const [selectedCharacters, setSelectedCharacters] = useState([]);
  const characters = ['Pawn', 'Hero1', 'Hero2'];

  const handleCharacterSelect = (character) => {
    if (selectedCharacters.length < 5) {
      setSelectedCharacters([...selectedCharacters, character]);
    }
  };

  const handleUndo = () => {
    setSelectedCharacters(selectedCharacters.slice(0, -1));
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    setSelectedCharacters([]);
  };

  const isValidSelection = () => {
    // Check for at least one of each character type
    const characterCount = selectedCharacters.reduce((count, char) => {
      count[char] = (count[char] || 0) + 1;
      return count;
    }, {});
    return (
      characterCount['Pawn'] >= 3 &&
      characterCount['Hero1'] >= 1 &&
      characterCount['Hero2'] >= 1
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center">
      <h2 className="text-2xl mb-4">Select Your Characters</h2>
      <div className="mb-4">
        {characters.map((char) => (
          <button
            key={char}
            onClick={() => handleCharacterSelect(char)}
            className="bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded m-2"
          >
            {char}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="mb-4">
        <button
          onClick={handleUndo}
          className="bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded m-2"
        >
          Undo
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={handleReset}
          className="bg-yellow-500 hover:bg-yellow-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded m-2"
        >
          Refresh
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="mb-4">
        <p>Selected Characters: {selectedCharacters.join(', ')}</p>
      </div>
      {isValidSelection() && (
        <button
          onClick={() => onSelectionComplete(selectedCharacters)}
          className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
        >
          Go to Game
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

CharacterSelection.propTypes = {
    onSelectionComplete: PropTypes.func.isRequired, // Define the type of the prop
  };

export default CharacterSelection;


frontend/GameLobby.jsx
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
function GameLobby({ onJoinGame }) {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-screen bg-gray-800 text-white">
      <h1 className="text-3xl mb-6">HitWicket Game Lobby</h1>
      <button 
        onClick={onJoinGame} 
        className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
      >
        Join Game
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}


GameLobby.propTypes = {
    onJoinGame: PropTypes.func.isRequired, // Define the type of the prop
};

export default GameLobby;


frontend/src/websocket.js
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:5000');

socket.onopen = () => {
  console.log('WebSocket connection established');
};

socket.onmessage = (event) => {
  try {
    console.log('Message from server', event.data);
    // Handle incoming data, update game state, etc.
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error processing message', error);
  }
};

socket.onerror = (error) => {
  console.error('WebSocket error', error);
};

socket.onclose = (event) => {
    if (event.wasClean) {
      console.log(`WebSocket closed cleanly, code=${event.code}, reason=${event.reason}`);
    } else {
      console.error(`WebSocket connection closed unexpectedly, message = ${event.data}`);
    }
  };

export default socket;


frontend/src/components/GameWindow.jsx
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import useWebSocket from '../hooks/useWebSocket'; // Custom hook for WebSocket

const GameWindow = () => {
    const [gameState, setGameState] = useState(null);
    const [selectedCharacter, setSelectedCharacter] = useState(null);
    const [validMoves, setValidMoves] = useState([]);
    const [moveHistory, setMoveHistory] = useState([]);

    const handleMessage = (data) => {
        const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
        if (parsedData.type === 'GAME_STATE') {
            setGameState(parsedData.gameState);
            setMoveHistory(parsedData.gameState.moveHistory);
        }
    };

    const sendMessage = useWebSocket('ws://localhost:5000', (message) => {
        const data = JSON.parse(message);
        if (data.type === 'GAME_STATE') {
          setGameState(data.gameState);
          setMoveHistory(data.gameState.moveHistory);
        }
      });
    
    useEffect(() => {
        // Effect to handle WebSocket messages if needed outside the hook's callback
        // Currently, all logic is handled within the hook's message handler.
        // Remove this effect if unnecessary.
      }, []); // Empty dependency array since WebSocket is managed within the hook
    

    const handleCharacterClick = (character) => {
        // Fetch valid moves for the selected character
        // Update state with valid moves
        setSelectedCharacter(character);
    };

    const handleMove = (move) => {
        // Send move to server via WebSocket
        sendMessage(JSON.stringify({ type: 'MOVE', move }));
    };

    return (
        <div className="game-window">
            <div className="grid grid-cols-5 gap-1">
                {/* Render game board here */}
            </div>
            <div className="move-controls">
                {/* Render valid moves and handle move actions */}
            </div>
            <div className="move-history">
                {/* Render move history */}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default GameWindow;


frontend/src/hooks/useWebSocket.js
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const useWebSocket = (url = 'ws://localhost:5000', onMessage = () => {}) => {
  const webSocketRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Initialize WebSocket
    const webSocket = new WebSocket(url);
    webSocketRef.current = webSocket;

    // Handle WebSocket events
    webSocket.onopen = () => {
      console.log('WebSocket connection opened');
    };

    webSocket.onmessage = (event) => {
      onMessage(event.data);
    };

    webSocket.onclose = () => {
      console.log('WebSocket connection closed');
    };

    webSocket.onerror = (error) => {
      console.error('WebSocket error', error);
    };

    // Cleanup function to close WebSocket on component unmount or URL change
    return () => {
      if (webSocketRef.current) {
        webSocketRef.current.close();
        console.log('WebSocket connection closed on cleanup');
      }
    };
  }, [url, onMessage]);  // Re-run effect only if url or onMessage changes

  // Function to send a message via WebSocket
  // Send a message via WebSocket
const sendMessage = (message) => {
    if (webSocketRef.current && webSocketRef.current.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
      try {
        const jsonMessage = JSON.stringify(message);
        webSocketRef.current.send(jsonMessage);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to send message:', error);
      }
    }
  };
  

  return sendMessage;
};

export default useWebSocket;


frontend/App.jsx
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import GameLobby from './GameLobby';
import CharacterSelection from './CharacterSelection';
import GameWindow from './components/GameWindow';

import socket from './websocket';  // Import the WebSocket service

function App() {
  const [gameState, setGameState] = useState('lobby');
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  const [characters, setCharacters] = useState([]);

  const handleJoinGame = () => {
    setGameState('characterSelection');
  };

  const handleSelectionComplete = (selectedCharacters) => {
    setCharacters(selectedCharacters);
    setGameState('gameWindow');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Additional setup or cleanup for WebSocket
    return () => {
      socket.close();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {gameState === 'lobby' && <GameLobby onJoinGame={handleJoinGame} />}
      {gameState === 'characterSelection' && (
        <CharacterSelection onSelectionComplete={handleSelectionComplete} />
      )}
      {gameState === 'gameWindow' && <GameWindow />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;



These are all the files. I'm getting error immediately after connecting to localhost but I'm able to do the functionalities up until selecting characters. When I select characters and click "Go to Game", I get black screen instead of game Screen.

